# Parsing content in scrapy from rootdomains and storing as txt

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to parse the text contents from root domains (e.g. apple.com) and store these in a dedicated domain.txt file. I am fighting now since a while and I am not able to get it right.

These are the functions in scrapy spider:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
        # Check if URL is text to avoid non-readable URLs
        content_type = response.headers.get('Content-Type').decode('utf-8')
        if not content_type.startswith('text'):
            return

        output_path = 'E:\\Altair_output'
        os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)

        # Extract all the links from the page
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()

        for link in links:
            if not self.is_valid_root_domain(link):
                continue

            parsed_link = urlparse(link)
            if not parsed_link.scheme:
                continue

            root_domain = self.get_domain_without_scheme(link)
            if not root_domain:  # Ensure root_domain is assigned a value before using it
                continue

            root_domain_url = f"{parsed_link.scheme}://{root_domain}"

            if self.is_german_tld(parsed_link):
                output_folder = f'E:\\Altair_output\\german_tlds\\{root_domain}'
            else:
                output_folder = f'E:\\Altair_output\\domains\\{root_domain}'

            if not os.path.isdir(output_folder):
                os.makedirs(output_folder)

            # Save new root domain
            if root_domain_url not in self.root_domains:
                self.root_domains.add(root_domain_url)
                filename = 'rootdomains.txt' if not self.is_german_tld(parsed_link) else 'german_rootdomains.txt'
                with open(os.path.join(output_path, filename), 'a') as f:
                    f.write(root_domain_url + '\n')
                    self.log(f'Added {root_domain_url} to {filename}')

            if root_domain_url and root_domain_url not in self.visited_root_domains:
                self.visited_root_domains.add(root_domain_url)
                yield response.follow(root_domain_url, callback=self.parse_root_domain_content)

        # Increase the counter for domains processed and clean up if needed
        self.domains_processed += 1
        if self.domains_processed >= self.cleanup_threshold:
            self.cleanup_domains()


        if root_domain not in self.domain_url_count:
            self.domain_url_count[root_domain] = 1
        else:
            self.domain_url_count[root_domain] += 1

        if self.domain_url_count[root_domain] > 250:
            self.log(f'URL limit reached for {root_domain}. Stopping further crawling.')
            return
        
   
    def handle_root_domain_response(self, response, root_domain):
        # Request the content of the root_domain
        return response.follow(root_domain, callback=self.parse_root_domain_content)


    def parse_root_domain_content(self, response):
        parsed_url = urlparse(response.url)
        root_domain_name = tldextract.extract(parsed_url.netloc).registered_domain
        output_path = 'E:\\Altair_output'
        
        if self.is_german_tld(parsed_url):
            output_folder = os.path.join(output_path, "german_tlds", root_domain_name)
        else:
            output_folder = os.path.join(output_path, "domains", root_domain_name)
        os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

        datetime_now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, self.generate_filename(response.url))

        text_content = ' '.join(response.xpath('//body//text()[not(ancestor::script) and not(ancestor::style)]').extract()).strip()
        cleaned_text = self.clean_text(text_content)
        truncated_text = self.truncate_text(cleaned_text, 3500)

        with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            # Write text and metadata to file
            f.write(f'URL: {response.url}\n')
            f.write(f'Datetime: {datetime_now}\n')
            f.write(f'Rooturl: {parsed_url.scheme}://{parsed_url.netloc}\n')
            word_count = len(cleaned_text.split())
            f.write(f'Word count: {word_count}\n')
            f.write(f'Text: {truncated_text.encode("utf-8", "ignore").decode("utf-8")}\n')
            for meta in response.xpath("//meta"):
                name = meta.xpath("@name").get()
                content = meta.xpath("@content").get()

                if name and content:
                    f.write(f'{name}: {content}\n')

            self.log(f'Saved file {output_file}')

def generate_filename(self, url):
        parsed_url = urlparse(url)
        root_domain = parsed_url.netloc.split('.')[-2]
        path = parsed_url.path.strip('/').replace('/', '_').replace(".", "-")
        invalid_chars = ['?', '\\', '/', '*', '<', '>', '|', ':', '&', '=']
        for char in invalid_chars:
            path = path.replace(char, '-')
        if len(path) > 100:
            path = path[:100]
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        return f'{root_domain}_{path}_{timestamp}.txt'

    def clean_text(self, text):
            """
            Remove unnecessary white spaces and new lines from text, and remove empty paragraphs if there are two in a row.
            """
            lines = text.split('\n')
            cleaned_lines = []
            previous_line_empty = False
            for line in lines:
                if not line.strip():
                    # Empty line, skip it
                    continue
                if previous_line_empty and not line.startswith('-'):
                    # Two empty lines in a row, skip the second one
                    continue
                cleaned_words = []
                words = line.split()
                for i, word in enumerate(words):
                    # Remove unnecessary white spaces
                    if i > 0 and word == ' ' and words[i-1] == ' ':
                        continue
                    cleaned_words.append(word)
                cleaned_line = ' '.join(cleaned_words)
                # Remove white spaces at the start of the line
                if cleaned_line.startswith(' '):
                    cleaned_line = cleaned_line[1:]
                cleaned_lines.append(cleaned_line)
                previous_line_empty = not bool(cleaned_line)
            cleaned_text = '\n'.join(cleaned_lines)
            return cleaned_text.strip()
        
    def truncate_text(self, text, max_words):
        words = text.split()
        if len(words) > max_words:
            words = words[:max_words]
        return ' '.join(words)
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks a lot!!

I tried setting:

```
if root_domain_url and root_domain_url not in self.visited_root_domains:
                self.visited_root_domains.add(root_domain_url)
                yield response.follow(root_domain_url, callback=self.parse_root_domain_content)
```

and

```
def handle_root_domain_response(self, response, root_domain):
        # Request the content of the root_domain
        return response.follow(root_domain, callback=self.parse_root_domain_content)
```

I sometimes (not in the latest version) got partial results but never consistent. I also tried with async methods for parsing and handling_root_domain_response, but that was also not working.